# Can we declare two strategies in passportjs?

Tags: node.js, role-base-authorization

I have Admin and user models in mongoose.I have to implement authorization to the routes(access controls). Question Is Can we make two passport strategies one for admin and one for user, and use those in user and admin routes. In this way, user wont be allowed to enter the admin routes.

Is this solution is okay or is there other better ways

Comment: Do you mean using two different strategies (like local and twitter) or two duplicate strategies (two locals)?

Comment: two locals, one to look up user database and other to look up admin database. both strategies to be used in subsequent user and admin routes to authorize. can we do this>

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to validate if a user is admin or regular user before allowing it to access the route, correct?

You can create a middleware that will check the user role before moving to the controller.

And, yes. You can create different strategies, but for your goal, you should be considering including a middleware to authorize the user based on its roles.

Comment: so for this, is it practical to store user role in data base? for example for every user There is type (normal user or admin)?

but for this,
 we will be fetching user 2 times. One in the middleware  to check the role. and other one in passport.js

Comment: Yes, it is. A regular user and an admin user are still one resource, just with different roles/permissions. So basically, you can use one strategy on Passport.js and just validate if the user trying to access the route have permission to do so.

It's been a while since I've used Passport.js but if I remember correctly, it works as a middleware for authentication/authorization. So basically, you just need one strategy to check user role on authorization.